# Can Windows Server 2003 (32 bit) host a 64 bit boot image for WDS?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-7, 32bit-64bit, wds

I'm running WDS on a Windows Server 2003 (32 bit) system and need to capture a Windows 7 (64 bit) image and then image a lab of computers with the 64 bit image.

Can my 32 bit server host a 64 bit boot image, as well as capture a 64 bit machine for imaging? If not, can I use a 32 bit boot image to capture an image from the Windows 7 (64 bit) machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, yes.  Regardless of your host OS architecture, WDS can host all three (x86, amd64, ia64) types of boot images without issue (and OS images for that matter).  The server isn't actually running anything in those images.  It's just serving them up as files to the PXE clients through TFTP.

The client machines are what actually boot the boot image.  And as far as capturing goes, that all happens on the client as well while it's booted into WinPE